Get current location in Android Development
I have a service worker that runs every 10 minutes and needs to get the current latitude and longitude every time it runs and I've been using the following code:
private var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(applicationContext)

override fun doWork(): Result {
val priority = Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
val cancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource()

fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(priority, cancellationTokenSource.token)
            .addOnSuccessListener { location ->
                Log.e("Location", "location is found: $location")
                curLat = location.latitude
                curLong = location.longitude
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.e("Location", "Oops location failed with exception: $exception")
            }
}

Unfortunately, location is always null.
Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/72038138/4696054 and several other answers: "If the location subsystem wasn't already on, it doesn't know what the location was, so it returns null. If you want to ensure that you don't get null, request updates."
This "request updates" part is confusing to me. I just need to get the location once when the service starts.
How am I able to do that and where do I initialize the location service for the update (other answers I found have been deprecated)?
Service worker does not have "OnCreate" method where I can initialize the location service for
https://developer.android.com/develop/sensors-and-location/location/request-updates and LocationRequest has been deprecated (at least Create () is deprecated).
Granted Permissions are:
android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and
android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
EDIT:
Per @CommonWare I tried:
val currentBuilder = CurrentLocationRequest.Builder().setDurationMillis(30000)
currentLocationRequest = currentBuilder.build()
fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(currentLocationRequest, null)
            .addOnSuccessListener { location ->
                Log.e("Location", "location is found: $location")
                curLat = location.latitude
                curLong = location.longitude
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.e("Location", "Oops location failed with exception: $exception")
            }

Unfortunately, location is still null

"I just need to get the location once when the service starts" -- the device might not have the location at that point in time, especially when you are requesting high-accuracy locations. That requires GPS, and the GPS is not on all the time, in part due to power consumption. You also cannot get the location while in the background without requesting suitable permissions. You might consider using the getCurrentLocation() that takes a CurrentLocationRequest as a parameter, and give that request a longer timeout, to see if that helps.

@CommonsWare Thank you. So I use fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(CurrentLocationRequest)? What is CurrentLocationRequest, where do I initialize it and what value should I give it?

"What is CurrentLocationRequest" -- it is a Java class in the Play Services SDK. "where do I initialize it" -- as with much of Play Services SDK, CurrentLocationRequest uses the builder pattern. You can create a CurrentLocationRequest.Builder instance via its zero-argument constructor, call setters on it, and then call build() to get your CurrentLocationRequest.

"what value should I give it?" -- the maximum duration via this mechanism is 30 seconds, according to the documentation. I do not know what duration is used for the particular getCurrentLocation() method that you are using. If it seems like it takes 30 seconds for you to get null, then perhaps the duration will not help, and your problem lies elsewhere. Otherwise, try setting the duration to 30 seconds, and see if that helps.

Also is FusedLocationProviderClient the way to go? Are there other better ways?

I do not know how you would define "better". getCurrentLocation() is the simplest solution, in terms of the amount of code required.

@CommonsWare, Thank you, unfortunately the location is still null. Please see the edit.

If you get null back quickly, then my guess is that this is a permission issue, perhaps with getting locations in the background. If it takes the full 30 seconds, and then you get null, then I am uncertain what might be going wrong.

It takes full 30 seconds

Consider using FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates instead of getCurrentLocation().

So here's how you can get your current location. I am skipping the permission part as you can do that yourself.
private fun isLocationEnabled(): Boolean {
        val locationManager: LocationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
        )
    }

 private fun getLastLocation() {
        if (isLocationEnabled()) {
           fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                val location: Location? = task.result
                if (location != null) {
                    //use the location latitude and logitude as per your use.
                    val latitude = location.latitude
                    val longitude = location.longitude
                }
            }
        }


Be aware, there is no guarantee on how "current" the lastLocation is. It could be minutes or even hours old, because this doesn't trigger an update of the location cache and just receives whatever is the latest location in the cache.

that's why i have used a boolean function isLocationEnabled because if it returns true last location would be always the current location.

No. isLocationEnabled just checks if at least one location provider is available. It does not check wheter a lastLocation is available at all. Or if a location is available how old it is ...

It depends on various factors like the device's location settings, available location providers (GPS, network, etc.), and whether the device has moved recently to trigger a location update. so as long as GPS is enabled it will update its last location. yes i agree that in some scenarios such as indoors or without network it might show some inaccuracy. bit it works fine for me.

"so as long as GPS is enabled it will update its last location" Not necessarily. Location updates only happen if at least one app on the device requests them. Just moving the device around won't trigger any updates (how would it? To know whether the device has been moved, you need to know the previous and current location ...)

you need to request location updates
try the following for instance

    val fusedLocationProviderClient =
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(activity)
    val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            val location = locationResult.lastLocation
            if (location != null) {
                val latitude = location.latitude
                val longitude = location.longitude

                // Use latitude and longitude for your purposes
                Log.d("Location", "Latitude: $latitude, Longitude: $longitude")

                // Remove location updates after receiving one
                fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(this)
            } else {
                Log.w("Location", "Failed to get location update")
            }
        }
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            activity,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        // Request permissions if not granted
        val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        activity.requestPermissions(permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSION_CODE)
        return
    }

    val locationRequest =
        LocationRequest.Builder(0L).setPriority(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).build()

    fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, null)


This worked for me
Mark user
    private fun markUser(googleMap: GoogleMap) {

      if(!checkLocationPermission()){
        requestLocationPermission()
      }

      if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
      ) {
        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
            .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                if (location != null) {
                    val latitude = location.latitude
                    val longitude = location.longitude
                    val userIcon =
                        BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on)
                    val userLocation = LatLng(latitude, longitude)
                    googleMap.addMarker(
                        MarkerOptions()
                            .position(userLocation)
                            .title("You")
                            .icon(userIcon)
                    )
                }
            }
       }
   }

Permission
private fun checkLocationPermission(): Boolean {
    val permission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
        requireContext(),
        permission
    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}

private fun requestLocationPermission() {
    val permission = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), arrayOf(permission), REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION)
}

@Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {
    when (requestCode) {
        REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION -> {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                shareCurrentLocation()
            }
        }
    }
}

When testing in Android Studio, default locations may be marked on your machine. Therefore, ensure to conduct tests on a mobile device.

The same remark for you as of the other answer using lastLocation:  Be aware there is no guarantee on how "current" the lastLocation is. It could be minutes or even hours old, because this doesn't trigger an update of the location cache and just receives whatever is the latest location in the cache.

To obtain the current location, you should use the FusedLocationProviderClient. For more details, refer to the following resources:

Changing location settings
Requesting location updates
FusedLocationProviderClient documentation


Yeah, that's correct. Still, fusionclient.ladtLocation does not trigger a location request a d just returns the last cached location of the device, regardless how old it is, or null, if there is no cached location
